# /Volumes/EFI - Firmware.scap & MBA41_0077_B12_LOCKED.scap

Tags: efi

Sorry for bad english - this is computer translation.
[image]

See figure - MBA41_0077_B12_LOCKED.scap (# 2) - is the actual firmware of my MacBookAir4,1, which is was used to update firmware, but that such Firmware.scap (# 1)? And the date of the change Firmware.scap 14.04.2016, although I have no new downloads, and even more so, no changes are made?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Hmm - that looks newer than Apple's page that sometimes isn't always updated: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518 - Are you looking to check you have the latest version?

Answer (score 4):

MBA41_0077_B12_LOCKED.scap is the payload of the EFI 2015-001 Security Update provided by Apple. It's visible in the EFI partition because your Mac can flash scap files (ROM updates) only from an EFI partition (fat32).

Firmware.scap is part of your OS X. The file is needed in the boot process (that is why you can see it in your EFI partition ) and is taken (copied) by OS X, during the boot, from /usr/standalone/i386/

Their presence in the EFI partition is not necessary (as MBA41_0077_B12_LOCKED.scap has already been flashed to the ROM and Firmware.scap if removed would be copied back), they are not malicious files.

Comment: >The file is needed in the boot process...You can from this point in detail?

Comment: >because your Mac can flash scap files (ROM updates) **only from an EFI partition** (fat32). And how:`/usr/sbin/bless -mount / -firmware ~/Desktop/MBA41_0077_B12_LOCKED.scap —recovery —verbose`?